# Error - Can't call method "domain" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, email, smtp

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Net::SMTP;

$smtp = Net::SMTP->new('mailhost');
print $smtp->domain,"\n";
$smtp->quit;
```

I run this pl file and get an error

> Can't call method "domain" on an undefined value

and in this pl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Net::SMTP;

$smtp = Net::SMTP->new('mailhost');

$smtp->mail($ENV{USER});
$smtp->to('postmaster');

$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: postmaster\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("A simple test message\n");
$smtp->dataend();

$smtp->quit;
```

I get an error

> Can't call method "mail" on an undefined value

What causes the errors and how can I solve them?

Answer (score 2):

Has it occured to you that `Net::SMTP` may have had problems finding your `mailhost`, and establishing an SMTP connection? I see that you took your scripts directly from the documentation – you do have to supply an actual value for `mailhost`.

If you had read the documentation a bit further, especially to the documentation for the `new` method, you'd have found [this interesting snippet](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SMTP#CONSTRUCTOR):

> #### new ( [ HOST ] [, OPTIONS ] )
>
> This is the constructor for a new `Net::SMTP` object. `HOST` is the name of the remote host to which an SMTP connection is required.
>
> On failure `undef` will be returned and `$@` will contain the reason for the failure.

So let's print out that reson for failure:

```
my $mailhost = "your mailhost";
my $smpt = Net::SMTP->new($mailhost) or die "Can't connect to $mailhost: $@";
```

`die` aborts your program with an error message. This message should tell you more about the actual error.

Do note that the example code in the documentation is not neccessarily meant to be used for real projects – it is just there to showcase the capabilities of the module. For real code, *always* `use strict; use warnings` at the top of your code, and declare all your variables with `my`. This helps finding more errors.